# Post Route not Stop working laravel

Tags: laravel-routing

I am Creating an Application and need a Professional Help as

`Route::post(....)` not working inside `Route::group()`

but working perfect outside `Route:group()`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it was about validation and it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

i got answered by some others source but want to answer so may someone else could get some help, my problem was that in laravel routing

using:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function(){
       // Some Functionality
});
```

Validation was not working

so the answer is that just to change the upper statement like below

using:

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => 'web'], function(){
       // Some Functionality
});
```

And the Magic Works